# Disable USB autosuspend for Wester Digital My Passport Ultra

Tags: usb, suspend

I recognize this question has been asked on these forums before but I'm having no luck with any of the solutions.  Here's my situation.  I recently purchased an Intel Nuc.  Ubuntu is stored on an SSD, my media is stored on a Western Digital My Passport Ultra.  I realize this is not optimal, but it's what I have...

This computer is supposed to be my media server but after a while sitting idle the connected harddrive disables therefore rendering it useless.  This is obviously a problem.  I can't pull out the harddrive as it does not have SATA connectors.

I do not have powertop, powernap or laptop power management stuff installed it's just straight Ubuntu, no bells or whistles.

Here is my drive after running "lsusb"
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1058:0827 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.

I'm incredibly new to linux, meaning three days have passed since I installed, so anything you could do would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own udev rule. Create file: **/etc/udev/rules.d/usb-power.rules**.

Try this rule:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="1058", ATTR{idProduct}=="0827", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"
```